# Block Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c++, c, caching

I want to perform a block matrix multiplication(Divide a matirix into multiple sxs matrices and multiply the corresponding blocks). I have written the code as following the sample code of architecture book of Hennesy:

```
for(int jj=0;jj<=(n/s);jj += s){
            for(int kk=1;kk<=(n/s);kk += s){
                    for(int i=1;i<=(n/s);i++){
                            for(int j = jj; j<=((jj+s-1)>(n/s)?(n/s):(jj+s-1)); j++){
                                    temp = 0;
                                    for(int k = kk; k<=((kk+s-1)>(n/s)?(n/s):(kk+s-1)); k++){
                                            temp += b[i][k]*a[k][j];
                                    }
                                    c[j][i] += temp;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Here, nxn is the size of original matrix. a, b matrices are of same size. I am dividing a,b matrices into blocks of size sxs. In my program, i have given block size to be 4. I put all elements of a, b as 5, a constant and n = 1000. However, i am getting wrong values in my result. Am i doing something wrong here? Stuck on this from past 2 hours. Can you guys please help if possible. The reference code in book is like this:

```
for (jj = 0; jj <= size; jj += N) {
    for (kk = 1; kk <= size; kk += N) {
        for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            for (j = jj; j <= findMin(jj+N-1, size); j++) {
                temp = 0;
                for (k = kk; k <= findMin(kk+N-1, size); k++) {
                    temp += B[i][k] * A[j][k];
                }
                C[j][i] += temp;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Here, s=N and size = n/s

Comment: Can you distill this into a small sample code with input that produces the problem and explain what you expect the answer to be?

Comment: Voting to close as why isn't this code working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int jj=0;jj<N;jj+= s){
        for(int kk=0;kk<N;kk+= s){
                for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                        for(int j = jj; j<((jj+s)>N?N:(jj+s)); j++){
                                temp = 0;
                                for(int k = kk; k<((kk+s)>N?N:(kk+s)); k++){
                                        temp += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
                                }
                                c[i][j] += temp;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

AxB
size is N

Answer (score 2):

The error is on this line.  You have

```
 temp += b[i][k]*a[k][j];
```

and you should have

```
 temp += b[i][k]*a[j][k];
```

instead.

It would also be nicer if you could put this piece in a function instead of this line:

```
((jj+s-1)>(n/s)?(n/s):(jj+s-1));
```

Comment: Thanks. I put it there because calling function so many times is not good for performance. And thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @JustinCarrey "calling function so many times is not good for performance" this is not true. Value readability first, performance only if it demonstrably a problem.

Comment: completely agree with @Andrei.  If you are really concerned about that you can use the keyword "inline".  Btw.  In this case the compiler will inline it for you so you don't even need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance I'm surprised to see both 0 and 1 starting indexes and <= for loop termination tests.  Books with either fortran or matlab code sometimes have 1 based indexing assumed whereas c/c++ uses 0 based indexing.

You could also implement and/or test the inner two for loops separately, since they will be for single-block matrix multiplication.

I would keep the findMin function separate instead of inlining it in the loop test.